# Discord.js V13 player.getQueue() returns undefined even tho a queue exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot with queue system. A queue is created in `play.js` file. The queue is then fetched in `skip.js` using `player.getQueue()` method to be able to skip songs. However, it returns undefined meaning no queue was found.

I know for a fact a queue exist because I logged it in the console but somehow this methode can't find it.

**play.js Code :**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

const { Player, QueryType } = require('discord-player');

module.exports = {

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()

        .setName('play')

        .setDescription('plays music')

        .addStringOption(option => option

            .setName("song")

            .setDescription("what to play")

            .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction, Discord) {

        const voice_channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;

        const bot_channel = interaction.guild.me.voice.channel;

        if (!voice_channel) {

            await interaction.reply({

                embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                    .setColor('#FFDAB9')

                    .setDescription('You need to be in a voice channel to play music!')],

                ephemeral: true

            });

        }

        if (bot_channel && bot_channel.id != voice_channel.id) {

            await interaction.reply({

                embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                    .setColor('#FFDAB9')

                    .setDescription(`I'm already connected on ${bot_channel.toString()}`)],

                ephemeral: true

            });

        }

        const song = interaction.options.getString("song");

        const player = new Player(interaction.client);

        const searchResult = await player.search(song, {

            requestedBy: interaction.user,

            searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO

        }).catch(() => { });

        if (!searchResult || !searchResult.tracks.length) {

            return interaction.reply({ content: 'No music found!', ephemeral: true });

        }

        const queue = player.createQueue(interaction.guild);

        queue.options.initialVolume = 50;

        queue.options.leaveOnEmptyCooldown = 5000;

        try {

            if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(voice_channel);

        } catch {

            void player.deleteQueue(interaction.guildId);

            return void interaction.reply({ content: "Could not join your voice channel!", ephemeral: true });

        }

        searchResult.playlist ? queue.addTracks(searchResult.tracks) : queue.addTrack(searchResult.tracks[0]);

        if (!queue.playing) {
            
            await queue.play().then(queue.playing = true);

            // console.log(queue);
        
        }


        const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()

            .addComponents(

                new Discord.MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('pause')
                    .setLabel('⏸')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),

            )
            .addComponents(

                new Discord.MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('resume')
                    .setLabel('▶')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),

            );

        const play_embed = await interaction.reply({

            embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                .setColor('#FFDAB9')

                .setTitle(`${queue.nowPlaying().title}`)

                .setURL(`${queue.nowPlaying().url}`)

                .setThumbnail(`${queue.nowPlaying().thumbnail}`)

                .setAuthor({ name: ` | Now Playing`, iconURL: `https://imgur.com/krzRxsN.png` })

                .addField('Duration :', `\`${queue.nowPlaying().duration}\``, true)

                .addField('Author :', `\`${queue.nowPlaying().author}\``, true)

                .setTimestamp()

                .setFooter({ text: `Requested By ${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: `${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}` })

            ],

            // components: [row]

        });

    }

}
```

**skip.js Code :**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

const { Player, QueryType } = require('discord-player');

module.exports = {

    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()

        .setName('skip')

        .setDescription('skips to the next music in queue'),

    async execute(interaction, Discord) {

        await interaction.deferReply();

        const player = new Player(interaction.client);

        console.log(player.queues);

        const queue = player.getQueue(interaction.guildId);

        // console.log(queue);

        if (!queue || !queue.playing) return void interaction.followUp({ content: "❌ | No music is being played!" });

        const currentTrack = queue.current;

        const success = queue.skip();

        return void interaction.followUp({

            content: success ? `✅ | Skipped **${currentTrack}**!` : "❌ | Something went wrong!"

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ***index.js*** ,

```
client.player = new Player(client);
```

In execute function, pass `client` as an argument.

```
execute({interaction, client})
```

In **skip.js**, While getting the queue, Try this--

```
 const queue = await client.player.getQueue(interaction.guildId)
```